# Does JavaScript has currency format specifier?

Tags: javascript

I was looking for a JavaScript built-in specifier to convert number in currency, but concluded that there is nothing built-in...

So, Does JavaScript really has no currency format specifier?

Meanwhile, I did a Google search and found that the following lines of code  does this job

```
.ToFixed(0).replace(/./g, function(c, i, a) {
    return i && c !== "." && ((a.length - i) % 3 === 0) ? ',' + c : c;
});
```

Any other / better way to convert number to currency with some understandable lines of code?

Please advise.

Comment: Numeral.js,accounting.js

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

To parse numbers into a formatted stringwith Javascript.

**In browser, or node**

numeraljs.com/

openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/

**node only**

github.com/joeferner/node-sf

github.com/fhellwig/strformat

**Currency format helper**

github.com/Alir3z4/node-money-currencies

Comment: If you're just going to recommend libraries, at least show some example code how to use them